# Shopify Color swatches that open to a particular product page

Tags: javascript, jquery, shopify, shopify-template, shopify-activemerchant

can I archive that I have explained below :

like on one of the product I click on the green color variant, so instead of changing the product image to green, the product should redirect to the green product?

The example is here https://www.doyoueven.com/products/tie-back-tank-fuchsia-marl

and this website is also on Shopify

is there any app please let me know of code forum i have checked there is not forum solutions.

The color swatches code is here :

```
<div class="swatch clearfix" data-option-index="{{ option_index }}">
  <div class="header">{{ swatch }}</div>
  {% assign values = '' %}
  {% for variant in product.variants %}
    {% assign value = variant.options[option_index] %}
    {% unless values contains value %}
      {% assign values = values | join: ',' %}
      {% assign values = values | append: ',' | append: value %} 
      {% assign values = values | split: ',' %}
      <div data-value="{{ value | escape }}" class="swatch-element {% if is_color %}color {% endif %}{{ value | handle }} {% if variant.available %}available{% else %}soldout{% endif %}">
        {% if is_color %}
        <div class="tooltip">{{ value }}</div>
        {% endif %}
        <input id="swatch-{{ option_index }}-{{ value | handle }}" type="radio" name="option-{{ option_index }}" value="{{ value | escape }}"{% if forloop.first %} checked{% endif %} {% unless variant.available %}disabled{% endunless %} />
        {% if is_color %}
        <label for="swatch-{{ option_index }}-{{ value | handle }}" style="background-color: {{ value | split: ' ' | last | handle }}; background-image: url({{ value | handle | append: '.' | append: file_extension | asset_url }})">
          <img class="crossed-out" src="{{ 'soldout.png' | asset_url }}" />
        </label>
        {% else %}
        <label for="swatch-{{ option_index }}-{{ value | handle }}">
          {{ value }}
          <img class="crossed-out" src="{{ 'soldout.png' | asset_url }}" />
        </label>
        {% endif %}
      </div>
```

Thanks

Comment: Yes you can. It depends on your approach, you can use metafields or collections based on the product or navigation based on the product or tags if you like. There are apps as well if you like to achieve this. So there are different options but we will need to see what have you tried in order to point you to the right direction.